# Using State Hook - (state variable) is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
function Header() {
    const [keys, setKeys] = useState([]); //added

    const first = (e) => {
       var result = new Map()
       axios.post('http://localhost:8000/' + query)
       .then(function(response){
         var content=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)).data
         for (var i=0;i<content.data.length;i++){
           result.set(content.data[i].image_id, content.data[i].caption)
        }

         var key = Array.from(result.keys());  
         setKeys(key); //added
         var value = Array.from(result.values());   
       
      }).catch(err => {
         console.log("error");
         alert(err);
       });
     };

   const second = () => {}
    

 return (
   <div>
       <button onClick={(e)=> { first(); second(); }}/>
       <img src={require(`img/img${key[0]}.jpg`)}/>
   </div>
 );
}

export default Header;
```

I asked a question here [Using state with array,map / How to pass variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68916723/using-state-with-array-map-how-to-pass-variable) and from the answers I got I edited the code like this. However I still get this error -->'key' is not defined  no-undef

I thought maybe it has something to do with https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html (Only Call Hooks at the Top Level). But I can't figure it out.

Comment: Is it `keys` instead of `key`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state variable is `keys` not key. If you access key you will get key is not defined.

```
return (
   <div>
       <button onClick={(e)=> { first(); second(); }}/>
       <img src={require(`img/img${keys[0]}.jpg`)}/>
   </div>
 );
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is typo.

You wrote `keys` instead of `key`.

your code should be like:

```js
  const [keys, setKeys] = useState([])
  <img src={require(`img/img${keys[0]}.jpg`)}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with what you suspected

```js
const [keys, setKeys] = useState([]); //added

<img src={require(`img/img${key[0]}.jpg`)}/>
```

You've defined the state to be `keys`, but in your `img` tag you are accesing `key[0]`, hence it's saying `key` is undefined